# A flag to move using the Stack Exchange Android app only gives four sites to choose from

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, android-app, flag-dialog

In the Stack Exchange Android app I tried to flag a question as a better fit for another site. However, I only got the meta site of the current site, Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault to choose from. It would've been a great fit on Unix/Linux, but Server Fault kind of worked too.

Is this four-sites limit intentional? Does it have anything to do with my reputation points?

(Tagged as bug because that was the only thing I was quick enough to read before the error message disappeared. And then I got stuck on the rate limit when I clicked again. Please retag.)

Comment: Not a bug; by design. And matches the migration dialog of the full web application.